# How To Get Browser To Open From Same Folder?

Tags: google-chrome, settings, directory

I don't know how to make the title any more clear. Let me give an example - When I want to add an image to an article on my blog, I click "Browse" button in the image uploader, and then upload the image to the blog.

The problem is, when I want to upload another image to my blog, I want the browser to look into the same directory; but it's always takes me to the "Recently Used" directory.

Is there a way to change this? I hope I have made myself clear enough.

**EDIT:** This issue probably pertains to Google Chrome browser only. As you can see in the comments, it's fine with Mozilla Firefox.

Comment: I always thought browsers sort of learning that, which folder was the last used, i doubt there's a simple setting for this.

Comment: Which web browser do you use? At least Firefox does remember the last upload directory.

Comment: Yes, I thought so too, but it just doesn't remember... or is it only on my PC? I am talking about Chrome by the way, to be specific. Doesn't it happen to you?

Comment: "Recently Used" is a GNOME 3 feature intended to show you a list of the files/folders you used last. Is your images directory shown in there?

Comment: Yeah, I am getting used to it (I just learnt it's similar to what I want). The only problem is it also shows the files I deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like many have got adjusted with it, the way it is. FWIW, I realized that the "Recently Used" feature in Gnome/Unity shows the most recently changed / downloaded files (not folders).

Since I first download the image that I want add to my blog post, the image(s) is always shown among those "Recently Used". I didn't notice that at first.

The point is, I (and we) want the browser -- here we are talking about Chrome -- to use the same folder/directory as downloads and uploads location. That is, if I download a file, it should go to the "XXX" directory, and when I browse to upload a file, the browser should directly take me to that folder (XXX), instead of the default folders like Pictures, Downloads etc.

What you should realize is that the "Recently Used" feature does the same thing, but in quite a different way. *(I tried to make my point clear.)*